# issue with pg_restore s exit code when warnings are there

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

commands:

```
bin/pg_dump -b -o -Fc -Z 0 -p 5333 -U user template1 -f db.dump
bin/pg_restore -c  -h localhost -p 5333 -U user -d template1 db.dump
```

steps followed:

1. add new tables to DB and took dump
2. delete the newly added tables
3. try restore with dump file
4. restore exited with code 1 but still tables are restore successfully.

> error in pg_restore:
>      *pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: err-1:  table "test1" does not exist
>
>          Command was: DROP TABLE public.test1;
>
>      WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 2*

Is this the expected behavior for dump/restore feature with tables add/delete steps?

Comment: Try removing `-c` (`--clean`) option from `pg_restore`. If the table didn't exist already, then the attempted `DROP TABLE` produced by `-c` will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pg_restore` can be a pain in the neck if the tables of your target DB only partially overlap with the tables in the dump.

Using the `--clean` flag only partially solves the problem but you may still encounter errors for non-existing tables.

In my opinion your best shot is to delete your target DB (or delete-cascade the target schema) and go with the restore.

A similar question you may want to look at: [will pg_restore overwrite the existing tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603192/will-pg-restore-overwrite-the-existing-tables)